# How to set default properties for Ionic Components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'd like to set default properties for Ionic components (used with Angular 11).

Example: I don't want to repeat the position for all labels and would like to enforce a meaningful default for the whole application.

```html
<ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
...
<ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
```

I'd like to define the floating once for all labels I'm going to create within my application.